# How do I dynamically resize a static UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic height for static table cells with wrapping labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981071/dynamic-height-for-static-table-cells-with-wrapping-labels)

I am using a UITableView with static content. The view controller does not implement anything from the delegate or datasource protocols (because the sections and cells are all defined in the storyboard), just inserts the text content using the UILabels wired as IBOutlets.

But now I want to set the height of one particular cell dynamically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to define the height of the cell at runtime, you *must* implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the `UITableViewDelegate`. It's a bit of a pain, but it's the only way you'll be able to programatically calculate the height of the cell and return it to the table when the table need to display it.

Comment: It's not that much of a pain, because I can call super for all the other cells that work fine with the storyboard.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        return 70;
    }else {
        // return height from the storyboard
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```