# Adding UICollectionView into UITableViewCell with auto height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, ios9

I have `UITableView` with static cells (just 2).

In first static cell i am adding `UIView` as a cell Subview

For the second static cell i am adding `UICollectionView` also as a cell Subview

(as you can see on attached image)

So, what i am trying to achieve is when `UICollectionView` is populated with content the primary scroll to the view to be `UITableView` itself.

This is possible if we disable `UICollectionView` scrolling.

But exactly here is the problem:

To make everything to work properly i need to know `UICollectionView` height and to add it as cell height. But in my case i don't know this because i am adding more content to `UICollectionView` dynamically.

Maybe the real question is: Is it possible to update cell height after cell initializing?

P.S. I prefer this kind of structure instead of using `UICollectionViewHeader` because i want to change `UICollectionView` completely based on user interaction.

[image: As shown here]

Any ideas and directions are hardly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually calculate the height of the UICollectionView based on your data source. Then return that from (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method.
Then reload your table when your Collection View data source changes.

[This might be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560716/how-do-i-dynamically-resize-a-static-uitableviewcell)