# tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath Not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table view to display comments of users

I need to make height of each row dynamic depending on content height

i searched for it and i found

> **heightForRowAtIndexPath** Method

but it's not working or i don't know how to use it !

here's my code :

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
   let username = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

    let comment = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UITextView
    username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

    comment.text = comments[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.comments.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136946/ios8-possible-to-use-tableview-rowheight-uitableviewautomaticdimension-for
Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299319/why-uitableviewautomaticdimension-not-working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not implemented the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method correctly.  You should read up on [self sizing table view cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) as it will do what you want.

Basically, to use self sizing cells, for the `UITableView` you will set an estimated row height, and also set the rowHeight to a value of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (or `UITableView.automaticDimension` in Swift 4.2 or later) .

**before Swift 4.2:**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

**Swift 4.2:**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Set the estimated row height value to a value that closely approximates the rough average height of all the cells.  This helps iOS have an idea of how big the full `UIScrollView` content is.

Also, with self sizing cells, you will not implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` at all.  Each cell height is obtained from the constraints within each cell.

For a good guide on self sizing cells, check out [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/).

If you don't want to do self sizing cells, you can implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, but you need to return the correct height for each cell.  That logic will be up to you to determine based on the `indexPath` parameter. But you need to make sure that you return the height for each cell (specified by `indexPath`) in pixels (logical pixels).

Comment: i removed heightForRowIndexPath and used 


  self.myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 160
                           self.myTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: You need to make sure your cells are all set up properly with auto layout .  Without them sizing properly, it will not work.

Comment: you mean constraints ?

Comment: Yes, the autolayout constraints need to be set properly in order for the self sizing cells to know how big each should be.